# Generate a random string with n digits number (except 0 at begin) in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Someone can teach me how to generate a random string with n digits number.

Ex: n=3, myString = "001" or "002" or ... "999" (except number 0 at begin)

p/s: I am using Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: @lurker I used rand(0,n) and "%d" % rand(10**n). However, they generate a number not a string?

Comment: Ruby does have formatting methods for converting a number to a string.

Comment: @VuLe: `"%d" % rand(10**n)` generates a `String`. In fact it looks entirely correct to me, why do you think it is wrong? Is it just missing the leading zeros? In which case, try `"%0#{n}d" % rand(10**n)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
n.times.map { (0..9).to_a.sample }.join
```

Comment: I check on tutorialspoint.com/execute_ruby_online.php (ruby 2.0) Its working. But, I run on my environment (ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.3.5), I got error "undefined method `sample' for [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:Array" Could help me solve it?

Comment: @VuLe `Array#sample` isn't available in Ruby 1.8.7, it becomes available since Ruby 1.9.x

Comment: @YuHao yes. This works for me (ruby 1.8.7): n.times.map { rand(0..9) }.join

Comment: there is a mistake in my above comment. the working is: n.times.map { (0..9).to_a.choice }.join (using choice instead of sample in ruby 1.8.7)

Answer (score 2):

If it's for a password or something:

```
require 'securerandom'

random_number = SecureRandom.random_number(10**n)
formatted_number = "0#{random_number}"
```

Edit: If it doesn't need to be secure:

```
random_number = rand(10**n)
formatted_number = "0#{random_number}"
```

Comment: thank for your info. In my case, its not for password.